# Can't import Android project into Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

[image]

As you can see in the screenshot above when I try to add new android project in eclipse idea, I go to File->Import but I didn't find Android import source to select.

Thanks

Comment: Please read how to ask a question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems you have an eclipse idea without android adt bundle, you must add android adt bundle to your eclipse idea to able create android project using it.
to doing this please read this [tutorial](https://stuff.mit.edu/afs/sipb/project/android/docs/sdk/installing/installing-adt.html).

because of adding adt bundle is very difficult, I suggest you use android studio, an professional intelliJ-based idea for developing android applications. it's have every thing you need for android developing.
you can download it from [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html)

good luck!